# Who the heck is Baba Micchi?

Tags: active-raid

Both cours of *Active Raid* are now over, and I *still* don't know who Baba Micchi is!

As you will recall, Baba Micchi is apparently some person who Sena Souichirou knows, and whenever this person's name is mentioned, Sena has a rather visceral reaction.

The final mention of this person was in cour 2, episode 5 at around 17:37 - while Sena is riding around in the Senars Inc. garbage truck hoping to catch some of the petty criminals in action, a group of women mention Baba Micchi, prompting this reaction, followed by an "I knew it!".

[image: "Baba?!"]

But then the show cuts to a different scene, and Baba Micchi is never mentioned again.

Who on earth *is* Baba Micchi?

Comment: An enigma that will continue to haunt Active Raid forever.